# How to add a custom attribute value to product url in Magento 2

Tags: url-rewrite, magento2.2.3, product-urls

I am using Magento ver. 2.2.3 . I need to add a custom attribute's (brand) value to the product url, like :

http://domain.com/smeg/smeg-cooker-90cm-with-gas-hob-cream.html

For that i have overridden the frontend product model & router, but nothing works. Can anyone suggest the solution. ?

**etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Url"  type="Company\Module\Model\Url" />

<preference for="Magento\UrlRewrite\Controller\Router"  type="Company\Module\Controller\Router" />
```

**Company\Module\Model\Url.php**

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Model;

use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite;

class Url extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Url
{
    protected $urlFactory;
    protected $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\UrlFactory $urlFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager $filter,
        \Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolverInterface $sidResolver,
        UrlFinderInterface $urlFinder
    ) {
        parent::__construct($urlFactory, $storeManager, $filter, $sidResolver, $urlFinder);
        $this->urlFactory = $urlFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
    public function getUrl(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, $params = [])
    {
        $requestPath = $product->getRequestPath();  
        if (!empty($requestPath))
        {
             $params['_direct'] = $requestPath;
        }
        $baseUrl = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
        $productUrl = $this->getUrlInstance()->setScope($product->getStoreId())->getUrl(' ',$params);
        $_attributeValue = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
        $remainingUrl = str_replace($baseUrl, '', $productUrl);

        $productUrl = $baseUrl. $_attributeValue . "/" . $remainingUrl;
        return $productUrl;
    }
    private function getUrlInstance()
    {
        return $this->urlFactory->create();
    }
}
```

**Company\Module\Controller\Router.php**

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Controller;

use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite;

class Router implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
{
    protected $actionFactory;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $urlFinder;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        UrlFinderInterface $urlFinder
    ) {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->urlFinder = $urlFinder;
    } 
    public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        $identifier = explode("/", $identifier);

        if(isset($identifier[0]) && !empty($identifier[0])) {
            $urlKey = str_replace('.html', '', $identifier[0]);

            if($urlKey) {   
                $objectManager     = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

                $collection        = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');

                $productcollection = $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter(
                    [
                        ['attribute' => 'url_key', 'eq' => $urlKey], 
                    ]
                );
                $productInfo = $productcollection->getData();
                if(isset($productInfo) && !empty($productInfo)) {
                    $productId = $productInfo[0]['entity_id'];
                    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
                    $brand = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
                    $brandUrl = $brand . "/";

                    $replaceUrl = str_replace($brandUrl, "", $request->getPathInfo());
                    $rewrite = $this->getRewrite($replaceUrl, $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());    
                    if ($rewrite == null)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    $request->setAlias(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS, $rewrite->getRequestPath());
                    $request->setPathInfo('/' . $rewrite->getTargetPath());
                    return $this->actionFactory->create('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    protected function getRewrite($requestPath, $storeId)
    {
        return $this->urlFinder->findOneByData([
            UrlRewrite::REQUEST_PATH => trim($requestPath, '/'),
            UrlRewrite::STORE_ID => $storeId,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to get sure what your situation is: You have a rewrite for your product with request_path "smeg-cooker-90cm-with-gas-hob-cream.html" in the database. That product has the urlkey "smeg-cooker-90cm-with-gas-hob-cream" and you want that domain.com/smeg/smeg-cooker-90cm-with-gas-hob-cream.html route to that product page. Right? If not, please correct me.

Comment: I want that the request path 'catalog/product/view/id/2417/' should redirect to target path 'smeg/smeg-cooker-90cm-with-gas-hob-cream'

Comment: you mean request_path = 'smeg/smeg-cooker-90cm-with-gas-hob-cream' and target_path='catalog/product/view/id/2417/'  since catalog/product/view/id/2417 is handled by the Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View controller? OK, and what are your actual entries in your url_rewrite table for this product?

Comment: I do not have any entry for url rewrite for this product, i was using custom frontend url router to redirect to another url, without changing the url rewrites

Comment: Also, you had got it correct. I have a product with url key "smeg-cooker-90cm-with-gas-hob-cream" and i want to redirect it to "smeg/smeg-cooker-90cm-with-gas-hob-cream"

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess you must use `$identifier[1]` in your code since your request_path is  'smeg/smeg-cooker-90cm-with-gas-hob-cream.html' and therefore your array after split is `$identifier = [ 0 => 'smeg', 1 => 'smeg-cooker-90cm-with-gas-hob-cream.html']`. Then you get the urlkey smeg-cooker-90cm-with-gas-hob-cream and with that you look can load the product. Anyway I guess you can shorten the code and load the rewrite url with the second array entry of `$identifier`: `$rewrite = $this->getRewrite($identifier[1], $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());` should give you the rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to create ‘di.xml’ at the following location and add below code.
app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Url"  type=" Vendor\Extension\Model\Url" /><preference for="Magento\UrlRewrite\Controller\Router"  type="Vendor\Extension\Controller\Router" /></config>
```

After that you need to create one more file that will fetch default Magento URLs so you can override those urls easily. For that purpose you need to create ‘Url.php’ inside your custom extension folder path.
app\code\Vendor\Extension\Model\Url.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Model;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite;
class Url extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Url
{
    protected $urlFactory;
    protected $storeManager;
 
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\UrlFactory $urlFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager $filter,
        \Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolverInterface $sidResolver,
        UrlFinderInterface $urlFinder
    ) {
        parent::__construct($urlFactory, $storeManager, $filter, $sidResolver, $urlFinder);
        $this->urlFactory = $urlFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
    public function getUrl(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, $params = [])
    {
        $requestPath = $product->getRequestPath();  
        if (!empty($requestPath))
        {
                         $params['_direct'] = $requestPath;
        }
        $baseUrl = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
        $productUrl = $this->getUrlInstance()->setScope($product->getStoreId())->getUrl(' ',$params);
        $remainingUrl = str_replace($baseUrl, '', $productUrl);
        $productUrl = $baseUrl."custom-prefix/" . $remainingUrl;
        return $productUrl;
    }
    private function getUrlInstance()
    {
        return $this->urlFactory->create();
    }
}
```

At last step, we need to create ‘Router.php’ file at below location
app\code\Vendor\Extension\Controller\Router.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Controller;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite;
class Router implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
{
    protected $actionFactory;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $urlFinder;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        UrlFinderInterface $urlFinder
    ) {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->urlFinder = $urlFinder;
    } 
    public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $replaceUrl = str_replace("custom-prefix/", "", $request->getPathInfo());
        $rewrite = $this->getRewrite($replaceUrl, $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());    
        if ($rewrite == null)
    {
            return null;
        }
        $request->setAlias(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS, $rewrite->getRequestPath());
        $request->setPathInfo('/' . $rewrite->getTargetPath());
        return $this->actionFactory->create('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward');
}
protected function getRewrite($requestPath, $storeId)
   {
        return $this->urlFinder->findOneByData([
            UrlRewrite::REQUEST_PATH => trim($requestPath, '/'),
            UrlRewrite::STORE_ID => $storeId,
        ]);
   }
}
```